# Iterate over 3D numpy array and calculate percentage change for each sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a huge gap in knowledge of iterating, broadcasting and generally making looping code.

I have a set of sequences of size (2000,10,200). I want to take each (10,200) sequence and divide all 10 rows by the first row of that sequence to get the percentage change relative to the individual window only.

Additionally I only want to perform the divide operation on the first 100 elements of the 200 total.

The pseudocode using traditional for loops:

```
#Loop over each of the 2000 sequences
#Loop over each of the 10 rows
#Divide each row (first 100 elements) by the the first row-1 (first 100 elements) and save
```

Here's my attempt though it's not working and probably not the right way to do it. Any explanations on the code is much appreciated.

```
for sequence in data:
    for row in data[0][row]:
        data[0][row]  = data[0][row][0:99] / data[0][0][0:99] -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup**
Let's look a smaller example:

```
data = np.arange(72).reshape(3, 4, 6) + 10
data

array([[[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
        [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
        [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]],

       [[34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
        [46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51],
        [52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57]],

       [[58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63],
        [64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
        [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75],
        [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81]]])
```

---

**Solution**
First identify how many of the last dimension you want to divide

```
half_last_dim = data.shape[-1] // 2
```

Second, slice the second dimension with a length one array to keep the dimensionality and enable broadcasting

```
data[:, :, :half_last_dim] / data[:, [0], :half_last_dim]

array([[[ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 1.6       ,  1.54545455,  1.5       ],
        [ 2.2       ,  2.09090909,  2.        ],
        [ 2.8       ,  2.63636364,  2.5       ]],

       [[ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 1.17647059,  1.17142857,  1.16666667],
        [ 1.35294118,  1.34285714,  1.33333333],
        [ 1.52941176,  1.51428571,  1.5       ]],

       [[ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 1.10344828,  1.10169492,  1.1       ],
        [ 1.20689655,  1.20338983,  1.2       ],
        [ 1.31034483,  1.30508475,  1.3       ]]])
```

Assign back to `data`
Make `data` type float

```
# Only necessary because my example started with integers.
data = data.astype(float)

data[:, :, :half_last_dim] /= data[:, [0], :half_last_dim]
data.round(2)  # rounded for pretty printing

array([[[  1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,  13.  ,  14.  ,  15.  ],
        [  1.6 ,   1.55,   1.5 ,  19.  ,  20.  ,  21.  ],
        [  2.2 ,   2.09,   2.  ,  25.  ,  26.  ,  27.  ],
        [  2.8 ,   2.64,   2.5 ,  31.  ,  32.  ,  33.  ]],

       [[  1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,  37.  ,  38.  ,  39.  ],
        [  1.18,   1.17,   1.17,  43.  ,  44.  ,  45.  ],
        [  1.35,   1.34,   1.33,  49.  ,  50.  ,  51.  ],
        [  1.53,   1.51,   1.5 ,  55.  ,  56.  ,  57.  ]],

       [[  1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,  61.  ,  62.  ,  63.  ],
        [  1.1 ,   1.1 ,   1.1 ,  67.  ,  68.  ,  69.  ],
        [  1.21,   1.2 ,   1.2 ,  73.  ,  74.  ,  75.  ],
        [  1.31,   1.31,   1.3 ,  79.  ,  80.  ,  81.  ]]])
```

---

**More Explanation**
[See Broadcasting Rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules)
In order to get the broadcasting right, we want the thing we are broadcasting to match dimensions for all dimensions except the one we are targeting.  And for that dimension, we want length `1`

```
data.shape
(3, 4, 6)

data[:, [0], :].shape
(3, 1, 6)
```

Comment: Amazing, that you very much. That is a very elegant line of code. I will do some further reading but can I ask why does adding -1 not apply in this use case? data[:, :, :98] /= (data[:, [0], :98] - 1)

Comment: That's a question of how in place operations work.  What you wrote is to take the result of `(dataXtrain[:, [0], :98] - 1) ` and overwrite the values of `dataXtrain[:, :, :98]` with `dataXtrain[:, :, :98] / (dataXtrain[:, [0], :98] - 1)`.  What I think you mean to do is `dataXtrain[:, :, :98] = dataXtrain[:, :, :98] / dataXtrain[:, [0], :98] - 1` Or `dataXtrain[:, :, :98] /= dataXtrain[:, [0], :98]; dataXtrain[:, [0], :98] -= 1`

Comment: Yes I was just about to write this, I just changed it to be separate operations. Thanks again for your help!